# How to get Yandex panoramic images

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, yandex

Is there any way to get Yandex map's panoramic images with c# or javascript for asp.net application? I have latitude and longitude points of locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yandex maps API doesn't allow to show panoramic images on external websites.

Comment: well :) is there any way to get that images?

Comment: I think only to make preent screen. Google has similar functionality btw, called Street View